# Lexical error when posting object using RestKit 0.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit

I'm having some problems doing a simple post using RestKit 0.2. This is what my code looks like:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"title"]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[Feed class] rootKeyPath:@""]

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some.url.com"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

Feed *feed = [[Feed alloc] init];
feed.title = @"SomeTitle";

[objectManager postObject:feed path:/feeds parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

When I run the above code, I get the following log:

```
request.headers={
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "sv, en, nl, fr, de, ja, it, es, pt, pt-PT, da, fi, nb, ko, zh-Hans, zh-Hant, ru, pl, tr, uk, ar, hr, cs, el, he, ro, sk, th, id, ms, en-GB, ca, hu, vi, en-us;q=0.8";
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    "User-Agent" = "appName/1.2 (iPhone; iOS 5.1.1; Scale/2.00)";
}
request.body=[title]=Foobar
2013-02-13 12:05:55.450 appName[3672:330f] T restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:177 POST 'some.url.com' (400 Bad Request) [0.5037 s]:
response.headers={
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 99;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 13 Feb 2013 11:05:55 GMT";
    "Set-Cookie" = "cookieTextHere; domain=.some.domain.com; path=/; expires=Wed, 27-Feb-2013 11:05:55 GMT; HttpOnly";
    "X-Request-Id" = xxe131e73e638733519c44xxa6224aa3f2xx;
}
response.body={"title":"JSON Parser Error","errors":
"lexical error: invalid string in json text. [title]=Foobar"}
```

The REST server expects posts beeing in JSON format, but when I look at the above log I see that the request has content-type set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" - is this causing the problem? I tried changing this using

```
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];
```

... but that didn't work.

I have posted raw json data like {"title":"Foobar"} using www.hurl.it to the url without any problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also had this problen i changed Content-Type to text/plain then it is working fine

Comment: Ok, cool. What's the code for doing this? I tried [client setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/plain"], but the request.header still says "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

Comment: i dont knw ios. i used rest in GWT

Answer (score 0):

Blake Watters has reply [google group of restkit](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/restkit/expected%2420content%2420type%7Csort%3adate/restkit/tZgNNF8jL8U/1ECc3CDtx2QJ)

following, it's my implememtation:

1. SubClass from RKManagedObjectRequestOperation, if ur ManagedObject.

### EPObjectRequestOperation.h

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

@interface EPObjectRequestOperation : RKManagedObjectRequestOperation

@end
```

### EPObjectRequestOperation.m

```
#import "EPObjectRequestOperation.h"

@interface EPObjectRequestOperation ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSError *error;
@end

@implementation EPObjectRequestOperation

- (void) main
{
    [super main];
    if([self.HTTPRequestOperation hasAcceptableStatusCode] && self.error.code == -1016) {//Expected content type

        self.error = nil;
    }
}
@end
```

2.register subclass on RKObjectManager

```
[objectManager registerRequestOperationClass:[EPObjectRequestOperation class]];
```